# why is my log file empty when I use log4j2?

Tags: java, logging, configuration, log4j2, appender

please help me debug something-- I am getting an empty log file when I use log4j2.

Here is my log4j2.properties file:

```
# Root logger option
name=PropertiesConfig
property.filename = logs
appenders = stdout, file

# stdout will print logs on console
appender.stdout.name = consoleLogger
appender.stdout.type = Console
appender.stdout.target = System.out
appender.stdout.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.stdout.layout.pattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n


# file will print logs in file
appender.file.name = fileLogger
appender.file.type = File
appender.file.fileName=ProtScannerLog.log
appender.file.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.file.layout.pattern = %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

loggers=file
logger.file.name = log4j2.properties
logger.file.level = info
logger.file.appenderRefs = file
logger.file.appenderRef.file.ref = fileLogger

rootLogger.level = info
rootLogger.appenderRefs = stdout, file
rootLogger.appenderRef.stdout.ref = consoleLogger
rootLogger.appenderRef.file.ref = fileLogger

# added for debugging
# logs the SQL statements
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
# Logs the JDBC parameters passed to a query
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.type=TRACE
log4j.appender.hb=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender 
log4j.appender.hb.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
```

And my log4j2.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="WARN">
  <Appenders>
    <File name="File" fileName="ProtScannerLog.log" append="true"> 
        <PatternLayout pattern="%d %t %-5p %c{2} - %m%n"/> 
    </File> 
    <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
      <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
    </Console>
  </Appenders>
  <Loggers>
    <Root level="debug">
        <AppenderRef ref="Console" level="info" />
        <AppenderRef ref="File" level="error" />
    </Root>
  </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

When I run I get the log file in the directory I am running my code from, but it is blank.  I see the correct messages in the console.  I also would like to have this log file placed in C:\Users\username, but I am having trouble specifying that location.  Any help would be much appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It supposed to be comment, but I don't have a reputation so have to post it this way :)

I've just copy pasted your config and it generated the ProtScannerLog.log file with several lines in.
So it definitely not log4j2.properties config issue.

Regarding the location of the file I can suggest to replace:

```
property.filename = logs
```

by

```
property.filename = C:\\Users\\username
```

And then refer to the property in "appender.file.fileName" definition:

```
appender.file.fileName=${filename}\\ProtScannerLog.log
```

It would create the file under any folder you specify.